# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException was unhandled by user code HResult=-2146233079

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entityframework with repository pattern using database. I'm getting the following error when I try to connect to the database

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2146233079

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using database first development methodology for entity framework?

Comment: Please verify your database connection string present in app.config or web.config depending upon the type of application you have created. Is it pointing to the correct database name and sql server instance?

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to connect to an existent database but EF try to do code first you should follow this easy steps to prevents this error.

1. Remove your current connection string in your web.config
2. Find your .edmx file and make double click how you can see in the next image. [image]
3. If you see this screen after click on "Update Model From database..."
   [image]
   Make sure you mark "Save connection setting in App.Config as"
4. After that if you .edmx file are in a class library you should copy the connection string to your main project.

On other side if you don't see the screen of step 4 make sure that you have removed all connection string of your project.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was ***OnModelCreating*** method it self. So, I just removed this method from my DB Model class inheriting form **DbContext** and every thing worked fine for me. I guess it used the base class's method  instead of overriding it with an exception throw.

I looked on Google a bit and found this method is usually called once for mapping Tables to Model and it's results are saved in Cache and this is called repeatedly if you have disabled cache.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
}
```